# Right-aligned image in navbar visible when expanded, but invisible when collapsed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a website with a navbar. This navbar shall contain two logos, one in the left corner (the coat of arms), one in the right corner (the scout lily), and links as text in between.
The coat of arms uses the "navbar-brand" class.

See here:
[image: navbar wide screen]

On a mobile screen, it looks like this:

[image: collapsed view - navbar menu]

[image: uncollapsed view - navbar menu]

The collapsed view is how I like it, but in the expanded view, I`d like to have the lily not to be shown, like this:

[image: my wish]

I tried messing with the classes and IDs, but no progress yet. How do I achieve this?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-danger fs-5">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="Gau Franken" height="100" width="82"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">
            <h4>Selbstdarstellung</h4>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ">
          <a class="nav-link" href="gruppen.html">
            <h4>Gruppen</h4>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="links.html">
            <h4>Links</h4>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="kontakt.html">
            <h4>Kontakt</h4>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="impressum.html">
            <h4>Impressum & Datenschutz</h4>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="Pfadfinderlilie" height="100" width="82">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: You're using the wrong data attributes for Bootstrap 5, so I'm not even sure how this can work at all. Be sure you're following the [correct documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/collapse/#example).

Comment: FYI, it's a misuse of heading elements to use them as menu links. They're for document structure, not styling. Use Bootstrap's typography classes if you just want bigger text.

Comment: Why don't Bootstrap's [visibility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/display/#hiding-elements) work for this?

Comment: I used the Carousel Template from the Bootstrap 5 & Font Awesome Snippets VS Code Extension,  thats where data attributes come from. 
I`ll look into the visibility classes, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I added the classes `d-none d-md-block` to the image div for the lily, now it works as I want.

```
<div class="d-none d-md-block">
                        <img src="img/LilieClear.png" alt="Pfadfinderlilie" height="100" width="82">
</div>
```